# Fact and/or generic knowledge storage

Tags: database, database-design

How can generic facts be stored in a database such as '3 injured in Kansas fire' or 'Spain wins 2010 Worldcup'?  The end result would be to have some table(s) where if multiple entries for people being injured or multiple entries for sports scores - data could be queried/totaled.

desired query would be to see how many injuries have occurred in a date range.

Comment: The obvious answer - as strings in VARCHAR(4000) columns - is presumably not what you want.  So you should flesh out your requirements, in order that people can give you more helpful answers.

Comment: I refrained from providing that answer and instead gave an answer that is probably less useful.  :)

Comment: good point - ive updated the question a little bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For generic fact storage, [RDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) is probably your best bet. It was designed for just that sort of thing. There are a bunch of different ways to store triples, the easiest of which are probably just XML or N3 text files.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question, I think - I'd imagine some form of bayesian-filter-style-thing could come in useful for fabricating certain metrics such as the positiveness of the fact (injured => bad, fire => probably bad) => bad, (wins => good, worldcup => big) => "big good" :)

Comment: thanks for the answer - organizing and tagging values in the string is a good idea